SOLVED Filter column only with previous value
I would like to create a drop menu filtered with the value of the previous drop menu as you can see on the screenshot.


I want to only have the subset of my first dropdown value. For instance for "legumes" to only have the legumes and not the fruits.
But I don't know how to show only the values filtered based on the first drop down.

This needs working columns aka helper columns!

You want to create a dynamic dropdown.
First, you will need to have a match between your category and your subset.
You can't have empty cells in front of banana for instance. I detailled a few steps below :


In order to create your dynamic drop down, you need to have an array with those values, using the filter function, as shown below :

And the last step is creating a drop down from the dynamic list you've just created :

I hope this helps.

If understood correctly, then the following should work to make the data validation list the required list as per the selected dependent dropdowns!


• Working One: Formula used in cell D3
=HSTACK(SCAN(,A3:A10,LAMBDA(α,δ,IF(δ="",α,δ))),B3:B10)


• Working Two: Formula used in cell G3
=UNIQUE(TAKE(D3#,,1))


• Working Three: Formula used in cell H3
=FILTER(TAKE(D3#,,-1),TAKE(D3#,,1)=G11)


In Data Validation, Allow --> List And Source --> =H3#

